# How to replicate effect of NODE_PATH env var with jsconfig file

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app, theming

I'm working on a project for a company with several brands, each with their own website, and my goal is to be able to have a single React app that, when deployed, will theme itself according to the env vars of that brand's server.

My current structure for the project is:

```
my-CRA-project/
|
├── public/
│   ├── brand1/  /* static stuff for each theme */
│   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   ├── staticData.json
│   │   └── etc...
│   ├── brand2/ 
|   └── etc... 
|
├── src/ 
│   ├── themes/ /* sass vars for each theme */
│   │   ├── brand1/
│   |   │   └── _vars.scss
│   │   ├── brand2/  
│   |   │   └── _vars.scss
|   │   └── etc...
|   |
│   └── ...rest of src code
└── ...rest of project
```

And I'm setting

```
NODE_PATH=./node_modules;./public/brandN
SASS_PATH=./node_modules;./src/themes/brandN
```

for each brand to incorporate their specific files when building on deploy.

The issue is that the latest version of React deprecated the NODE_PATH variable and it now says to use a jsconfig.json file instead, which defeats the purpose I'm using the NODE_PATH var to begin with.

Is there any way to duplicate this behavior using the jsconfig.json file? Or even beyond that, is there a better way I could be structuring this entire project to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

you can use webpack and it's alias
for example in next js , it would go in component folder and then based on env go to sub folder

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          test: path.resolve(__dirname,`components/${process.env.test}`),
        }
      }
    })
    return config
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is an example jsconfig.json file for a JavaScript project. You can create the file if it doesn't already exist:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: I understand how to make the jsconfig.json file, the issue is that I need to be able to change the base url to match the brand/theme I'm deploying to (I'm running the apps on Heroku). With NODE_PATH, I could set the env var on heroku and have things resolve correctly on build, but the jsconfig.json file is static and gets placed in version control. It's that inflexibility I'm trying to get around.